# Rails cross model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I have two tables one for members and the other for employees, both have an attribute called `id_number` this attribute is not required and can be null.

Is it possible to run a validation to ensure the uniqueness of the `id_number`, so that if an employee is added with the same `id_number` as an member or vice versa that it will give an error.

I am thinking of writing my own validation but hitting the db for each instance will be very slow as some companies upload 10's of thousands of employees at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's possible with your own validation. I think you have to hit the database, otherwise you never could check if it exists already.

```
def your_validation
  employee_ids = Employee.all.map(&:id_number)
  member_ids = Member.all.map(&:id_number)
  id = self.id_number
  if employee_ids.include?(id) || member_ids.include?(id)
    errors.add(:id_number, "is already taken")
  end
end
```

I think adding an index to your id_number will be good.

UPDATE: The above method could be changed to following to improve the performance:

```
def your_validation
  employee_ids = Employee.all.map(&:id_number)
  if employee_ids.include?(self.id_number)
    errors.add(:id_number, "is already taken")
  else
    member_ids = Member.all.map(&:id_number)
    if member_ids.include?(self.id_number)
      errors.add(:id_number, "is already taken")
    end
  end
end
```

The first one is cleaner, the second one should be faster. But check this out with a lot of db entries and a benchmark tool.

Comment: yeah i recon adding an index will speed it significantly. it looks similar to the one that i am bashing out. only thing is i am sure yours will work haha. thanks man this is perfect

Comment: You could change the order of employee_ids.include? and member_ids include?...this could improve the speed, if you have much more  member than employee entries and vica versa, because if the first one already finds the new id_number the other case never will be executed. I will update my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want something like this:

```
def your_validation
  if self.id_number.present?
    if Employee.exists?(:id_number=>self.id_number) || Member.exists(:id_number=>self.id_number)
      errors.add(:id_number, "is already taken")
    end
  end
end
```

if you have indices on the id_number columns this check should run very quickly and is the same check that validates_uniqueness_of would use within a single table. Solutions that involves fetching all ids into rails will start running into problems when the tables get large.

Another thing to note is that if your app runs multiple web server instances at a time these kinds of rails side checks can't 100% guarantee uniqueness as they are subject to races between threads. The only way to ensure uniqueness in such situations would be to use facilities built into your database or generate the id_numbers yourself from a source that precludes duplicates (such as a database sequence).